# Converting a byte* to String in Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino, processing

I'm trying to request basic information from a server using an Arduino Uno and an ENC28j60 Ethernet Module. I've been using webclient.ino, an example from the Ethercard library. I am able to get data, but I'm having difficulty converting it into a string. Data comes in as a pointer byte (?) (like byte*) and I can easily convert it into a const char*. From, there, however, I don't know how to convert it into a String, which I can manipulate much easier. The critical part of my code is below. Full code is here: http://pastebin.com/kXdchwYd

```
   byte Ethernet::buffer[700];
   static uint32_t timer;

   const char website[] PROGMEM = "www.yoerik.com";

   // called when the client request is complete
   static void my_callback (byte status, word off, word len) {
   Serial.println(">>>");
   Ethernet::buffer[off+600] = 0;
   //How to get Ethernet::buffer+off into a string?????
   Serial.print(( const char* )Ethernet::buffer+off);
   Serial.println("...");
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The string class has a constructor that takes a null terminated C-string(a char array)

So really you could do:

```
    std::string str(ethernetCharArray);
```

But I'm fairly certain that byte is an unsigned char * itself, so you may be able to do this:

```
    size_t len;
    std::string s( reinterpret_cast<char const*>(EthernetByte), len ) ;
```